# Blazor + JSInterop for media recording

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-jsinterop

I am building a web app which allows users to record short audios < 20 seconds. I wrote some code and it works, but only if the audio is stopped when it's shorter than 3-4 seconds.

It's a C#, Blazor app that uses JSInterop. Whenever the recording lasts longer, attempt to stop it results in losing execution flow (that is some error happens somewhere, which is not caught and the calling method just exits the current method and the app keeps on running). Whenver this happens it shows for a short perion "Attempting to reconnect" error, so maybe it's blazor's websocket connection which dies while I record something?

Here's my code:

C#

```
  public async Task<string?> StopRecording()
        {
            var module = await moduleTask.Value;
            var jsonDocument = await module.InvokeAsync<JsonDocument>("stopRecording");
            if (jsonDocument == null)
            {
                // Happens when recording is too quickly stopped
                return null;
            }

            string recordingId = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("id").GetString();
            string base64String = jsonDocument.RootElement.GetProperty("data").GetString();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(base64String))
            {
                throw new Exception("Pronunciation data is empty");
            }

            await module.InvokeVoidAsync("showStartButton");
            await module.InvokeAsync<JsonDocument>("addRecordingListItem", recordingId, base64String, false, true);
            
            return base64String;
        }
```

JS

```
function base64ToBlob(base64String) {
    const byteCharacters = atob(base64String);
    const byteNumbers = new Array(byteCharacters.length);

    for (let i = 0; i < byteCharacters.length; i++) {
        byteNumbers[i] = byteCharacters.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

    return new Blob([byteArray], { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
}
export function addExistingEntryRecording(soundDto) {
    console.log(soundDto);

    addRecordingListItem(soundDto.soundId, base64ToBlob(soundDto.recordingB64));
}

export function startRecording(recordingId, lblRecord, lblStopRecording) {
    _lblRecord = lblRecord;
    _lblStopRecording = lblStopRecording;

    showStopButton();

    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true })
        .then(function (stream) {

            _latestRecordingId = recordingId;

            let chunks = [];

            mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
            mediaRecorder.audioBitsPerSecond
            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("dataavailable", function (event) {
                chunks.push(event.data);
            });

            mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", function () {
                const audioBlob = new Blob(chunks, { type: "audio/ogg; codecs=opus" });
                recordedBlob = audioBlob;
            });

            mediaRecorder.start();
        })
        .catch(function (err) {
            console.log("The following error occurred: " + err);
        });
}

export function stopRecording() {
    if (!mediaRecorder) {
        return;
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        mediaRecorder.addEventListener("stop", function () {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function () {
                const base64String = reader.result.split(',')[1];
                resolve({ id: _latestRecordingId, data: base64String });
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(recordedBlob);
        });
        mediaRecorder.stop();
    });
}
```

As I said, there are no errors visible, not thrown, not in browser's Console, not in VS's Output.

I tried wrapping my JS code into try-catch blocks - didn't produce any result, no errors were caught.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this WASM or server flavor?  I'm not a fan of transferring large blobs between js and C#.  My solution was to send  blobs as file attachments in a `fetch` command aimed at an MVC api, which saved it to disk and returned the path as a string-- which I then used as the source of an `<audio>` element.  Keep another thing in mind: if your site has a lot of users, you want as much of the media processing (in my case, converting to .mp3 format) pushed to the client as possible, to save your server from melting down.

Comment: @Bennyboy1973 it's server, I forgot why I went with it though :) But your ideas are super helpful, this is genius, I'll probably do the same. However, how do you handle reactivity? Do you use events to find out when a new sound has been pushed to a certain endpoint to update the UI?

Comment: I use recording in a few different ways.  For live chat (like listening for text to send to a chatbot), I actually monitor the mic level and start and cut the recording automatically based on the volume.  Technically, that's not an event, because you are constantly monitoring the audio until volume falls below a threshold.  Another way is to use push-to-talk: the user can just click on a button to record and release to stop.

Comment: Overall, I mainly recommend this: do 100% of media work in JavaScript.  This puts all the burden on the client, and saves your VM or whatever from excess processing.  I found it very hard to get everything working, as a lot of older samples and examples are obsolete now.  But it was worth the 10-20 hours of hair-pulling to figure out media in JS, especially https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder  (but I can see from your samples you're already well on your way to learning this stuff)

Comment: And yes-- APIs like speech to text provide a lot of events.  For example, Microsoft's speech to text provides timed viseme data in addition to the raw text.  This allows you to animate an avatar to look like its speaking (but there's no library for this, you have to literally switch the images using all your own logic).  It also give you the exact timing of every syllable in every word, so you could (if you wanted) highlight words or sentenences in text while your audio is played.  This is why a SQL database is so important: you need an easy way to store all the timings and so on.